# Why would someone or something want to steal the moon?

Tags: moons

Because another life form, ET maybe  wants it for his earth planet! A spaceship, like on  Star Trek (next generation) would surely have a enough force or the capabilites  to trip up the moon? Obviously aliens have surpassed or skill level. We don't even know possibilities. There are people that don't believe in aliens.

Comment: A villain stole the Great Pyramid, and this person wants to one-up them.

Comment: In all seriousness, this isn't the place to go to get plot ideas; it's the place to go to ask for ways to make a plot which you already came up with work.

Comment: Also, moving something moon-sized (which is Quite Big, after all) is going to be a significant challenge for any Star Trek ship, and space appears to be well stocked with rocks.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Picard once pulled a stellar core fragment away from collision with Earth using the tractor beam. The moon will be peanuts.

Comment: @Goodies episode-specific powers are risky things to rely upon. There's no guarantee that anyone will even remember that they existed 30-45 minutes after they were used.

Comment: @StarfishPrime a really skilled ST savant remembers the biosensor readings of planet Ixytlu.

Comment: They don't want to steal the moon.  They want to steal something buried deep in it but digging for it will be noticed by it's owners.  They can swoop in and make off with it with some sort of spacewarp faster than the owners can react.

Comment: To impress their non loving mother